# Angular 5 HttpClient Body Parameters not binding to MVC Core 2 Endpoint

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

Hello we are currently using c# MVC Core 2 and Angular 5 and we're struggling to understand why our endpoints are not having there information bound inside the action handler.

Here is our interceptor which sets all of our necessary information about the request..

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (this._cookieService.check('Abp.AuthToken')) {

        // We have our auth token..
        let bearerToken = this._cookieService.get('Abp.AuthToken');
        // Clone the request to add the new header.
        const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'bearer ' + bearerToken).set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')});
        // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
        return next.handle(authReq);

    } else {
        // @todo This should sign the user out of the application...
        console.log('here');
    }

}
```

Please note we've also tried 'application/json' as well to no success.

Below is our request made using the angular `HttpClient`:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:22742/api/services/app/UserGridSetting/SaveUserGridSettings', {'jsonData': JSON.stringify(gridSettingsObject)}).subscribe((d: any) => {
        console.log(d);
    });
```

Here is our C# corresponding endpoint:

```
 public async Task<int> SaveUserGridSettings(string jsonData)
    {

        return await _repository.InsertOrUpdateAndGetIdAsync(setting);

    }
```

The Endpoint is being correctly called and run but our jsonData is never bound into the method, we have tried a plethora of different things with the Angular client but the information is never bound in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer after several hours, the expected type of string was not able to bind our `jsonData` identifier from the `HttpClient` as it was checking for the `data` property on the primitive type string.

Simply adding a class and changing the signature to:

`public async Task<int> SaveUserGridSettings(ColumnState jsonData)`

With `ColumnState` being:

```
  public class ColumnState
    {
        public string data { get; set; }
    }
```

and using angular like:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:22742/api/services/app/UserGridSetting/SaveUserGridSettings', {data: JSON.stringify(gridSettingsObject)}).subscribe((d: any) => {
            console.log(d);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing 3 things:

1. Use content type "application/json" not "JSON/Application"
2. Post the string directly
   `this.http.post('http://localhost:22742/api/services/app/UserGridSetting/SaveUserGridSettings', JSON.stringify(gridSettingsObject)) //...`
3. Have the c# method like this:
   `public async Task<int> SaveUserGridSettings([FromBody]string jsonData)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though we have tried all of the above already with no success.

Comment: Just tried all of the above together, first two together provided just null and adding [FromBody] returns us back a bad request.

Comment: What if you try to call stringify twice: JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(gridSettingsObject)) ?
It's getting a bit ugly, but may do the trick